# How to represent a ListProperty(str) property with string formatting?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, string-formatting

I have a `ListProperty(str)`:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    tags = db.ListProperty(str)
```

Sometimes I need to edit the tags already written to datastore, so I created an edit page:

```
class EditItem(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""<div>
        <form name="submit_form" action="/edititemhandler" method="post">

        url: <input type="text" name="url" size=50><br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form></div>""")
```

This handles the form:

```
class EditItemHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
            query = Item.all()
            query.filter("url =", self.request.get("url"))
            e = query.get()
            self.response.out.write("""
            <form name="submit_form" action="/edititemhandlerhandler" method="post">
            tags: <input type="text" name="tags" size=50 value="%s"> <br />
            [other values]
            ...
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form> """ % (e.tags, .... ))
```

After I edit the tags I try to write `new_tags` back to the database:

```
class EditItemHandlerHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        query = Item.all()
        query.filter("url =", self.request.get("url"))
        item = query.get()
        logging.info("TAGS %s" % self.request.get("tags"))
        new_tags = self.request.get("tags")
        item.tags = new_tags
        [other items]
        ...
        item.put()
```

But this gives

```
BadValueError('Property %s must be a list' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property tags must be a list
```

But `logging.info` shows `self.request.get("tags")` to look like a list:

```
TAGS [u'speaking', u'glam']
```

If I do

```
    item.tags = [new_tags]
```

to turn `new_tags` into list I get

```
"[u'presidential', u'glam', u'family']"
```

which does not look like a list but looks like a string.

So, how do I format the list element with %s so that it stays a list? Thanks.

**Update**

I figured that I needed to convert tag list to string before updating and then convert it into list:

```
>>> tag_list = [u'formal', u'flag', u'photo']
>>> tag_list_as_string = str(" ".join(tag_list))
>>> tag_list_as_string
'formal flag photo'
>>> #edit tags
>>> tag_list_as_string = 'formal flag photo newtag'
>>> new_tag_list = tag_list_as_string.split(" ")
>>> new_tag_list
['formal', 'flag', 'photo', 'newtag']
>>>
```

Do you know how I can get the `tag_list_as_string` with commas, like this,

```
'formal, flag, photo'
```

instead of like this

```
'formal flag photo'
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `ListProperty(str)` - use `StringListProperty()`. As it stands, you will only be able to store byte strings, which precludes all of unicode except the first 127 codepoints ('ASCII'). Likewise, don't use the str() function to stringify stuff.

Comment: For future reference, if your question edits substantially changes the type of answer needed, consider asking a new question *instead of* editing the current one, You cannot select the best answer both for the previous version and for the final version of your question.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Thanks. Changed to StringListProperty().

Comment: @Will: True, the question in my update can be a different question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tag_list = [u'formal', u'flag', u'photo']
print ", ".join(tag_list)
>> formal, flag, photo
```

Comment: Thanks. But now converting it back to a list I get an extra comma between items in the list; so I will leave it as is. All tags are one word anyway.

Comment: @Zeynel You need to update the split function to split on the commas as well.